# Is there in ExtJs 3 JsonStore event for when store is loaded?

Tags: extjs

I have to update my display when JsonStore has loaded all records, is there event for this event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The load event will work:

```
store.on('load', function(store, recs, opt){
     //update your display here
}, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

The "load" event is what you are looking for. See the online documentation :

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonStore